# Passing a struct as parameter to xTaskCreate - <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>

Tags: pointers, struct, parameters, arduino, freertos

When passing my struct to the function xTaskCreate and run it on my Arduino Uno I get a 0 as pin output and 1283 as delay output from the toggle_LED-function. Before, in the setup-function the data is correct. But when I pass it to the function and print from there the data is incorrect and as you can guess, none of my LEDs blink.
Kind of a rookie when it comes to pointers, so what am I missing here?
It compiles without errors, but doesn't work as expected.

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>

#define RED_PIN 6
#define YELLOW_PIN 7
#define GREEN_PIN 8


typedef struct LED_struct{
  int sPIN;
  int sDELAY;
} sLEDS;

bool debug_flag = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sLEDS sRED = {RED_PIN, 500};
  sLEDS sYELLOW = {YELLOW_PIN, 200};
  sLEDS sGREEN = {GREEN_PIN, 1000};

  Serial.println("SETUP: ");
  Serial.println(sRED.sPIN);
  Serial.println(sRED.sDELAY);
  Serial.println(sYELLOW.sPIN);
  Serial.println(sYELLOW.sDELAY);
  Serial.println(sGREEN.sPIN);
  Serial.println(sGREEN.sDELAY);

  xTaskCreate(toggle_LED, "Toggle LED via struct", 128, &sRED, 1, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(toggle_LED, "Toggle LED via struct", 128, &sYELLOW, 1, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(toggle_LED, "Toggle LED via struct", 128, &sGREEN, 1, NULL);
}

void toggle_LED(struct LED_struct *xStruct){
  pinMode(RED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YELLOW_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN_PIN, OUTPUT);

  while(1){
    if (debug_flag == true) {
      Serial.println("DEBUG: ");
      Serial.print("PIN: ");
      Serial.println(xStruct->sPIN);
      Serial.print("DELAY: ");
      Serial.println(xStruct->sDELAY);
    }

    digitalWrite(xStruct->sPIN, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(xStruct->sPIN, LOW);
    delay(xStruct->sDELAY);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

I've tried both with a local struct within the toggle_LED-function and without as I have it now.

Comment: Do you also call vTaskStartScheduler somewhere ? Also the main stack (stack until vTaskStartScheduler is called) is reset and reused as ISR stack by FreeRTOS on ARM Cortex-M at least. So you could define static struct variables to keep them in persistent memory and valid when used by the tasks. Oh and you really should increase the stack size of your tasks using stack hungry print functions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These structures

```
sLEDS sRED = {RED_PIN, 500};
sLEDS sYELLOW = {YELLOW_PIN, 200};
sLEDS sGREEN = {GREEN_PIN, 1000};
```

are local variables which are (temporary) placed on the stack and out of scope when `setup()` ends. Their memory is reused for other purposes.

Try

```
static const sLEDS sRED = {RED_PIN, 500};
static const sLEDS sYELLOW = {YELLOW_PIN, 200};
static const sLEDS sGREEN = {GREEN_PIN, 1000};
```

or place the structures at the file level (outside any function).

Comment: I fixed it by making them global and in my function toggle_LED I added this:
sLEDS local_struct = *(sLEDS *) xStruct;
uint16_t local_pin = local_struct.GPIO;
uint16_t local_delay = local_struct.sDELAY;
Then changed xStruct->sPIN to the new variables above.